# Deal with dynamic response in retrofit

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm receiving json like this

```
{
  "animal" : {
    "type" : "FIRE",
    "food" : "potato",
    "water": "7up"
  }
}

---

{
  "animal" : {
    "type" : "WATER",
    "water": "7up"
  }
}
---
{
  "animal" : {
    "type" : "CYPO",
    "counter": 7
  }
}
---
{
  "animal" : {
    "type" : "UNKNOWN",
    "food": "Stup",
    "water": "Cola",
    "counter" : 4
  }
}
```

Am I suposed to create 4 data classes? I mean, I know how they are going to look, they are not going to change, but depends of the type is going to have some parameters or not, so do I have to create 4 data class like for instance the FIRE one

```
data class AnimalFireResponse{
@SerializedName("type") val myEnum: MyEnum, @SerializedName("food") val food : String, @SerializedName("water") val water : String) 
}
```

But then I do not know what to put on my service

```
@GET("/dynamic/stuff.php")
fun getAnimal(): Call<List<MyResponseWithDynamicAnimal>>
```

Is there any other way way generic?

### Edit

Maybe it helps but, I know all the `type` values (FIRE,WAITER,CYPO,UNKNOWN) and I know all of them are going to return the same values, for instance FIRE is going to return always `food` and `water`, does it help to you guys?

Comment: Could be easily done using Volley.

Comment: Sorry but I'm using Retrofit, what's the difference?

Comment: In retrofit we usually create data class which maps with the JSON response. But if you you use Volley then you can loop through all the animal objects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make a single data class to represent this JSON. 
As the names of the fields don't change you can include them all and mark them as nullable.

Comment: I'd like to avoid nullable stuff, is there any other way?

Comment: Using nullable types is by far the easiest way. If you don't like to use nullable types because it affects the rest of your app you could simply use the type you use in Retrofit as an intermediary between your network response and your app types

Comment: Not getting you, could you provide a simple example?

Comment: Retrofit would return you a type with nullable values like I suggested. Then you would check these values and set them to whatever data class you are using in the rest of your app

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could create 1 data class with all the possible fields and use the fields accordingly. What i mean is:

```
data class AnimalResponse{
@SerializedName("type") val myEnum: MyEnum, 
@SerializedName("food") val food : String= "",
@SerializedName("water") val water : String= "",
@SerializedName("counter") val counter : Integer = -1) 
}
```

If your response doesn't contain a field, it will be initialized with a default value which you can check in your code. However, I feel like the API structure may not be well optimized.(I could be wrong, I am no expert on this)

Comment: This is the same as putting nullable, I'm not looking for this :(

Comment: do you have control on the api structure? can you change the json response format?

Comment: No, I can not do that

Comment: The only thing i could think of to have not null is to have the type field as a parent to other fields, something like:

animal: {
 type: "fire",
property: {
  food:"xyz",
  water:"abc" 
 }
} 

that way you can have a dataclass Animal(val type:Enum, val property:Any) and then have 3 other data classes containing food, water etc. But if you can't change the API i guess it's of no use. Hope you find a fix soon, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following DTO if nullable is ok

```
 data class AnimalResponse(
  val type: String?, 
  val food : String?,
  val water : String?,
  val counter : Integer?
 )
```